# Magento2: How to add Country and State field at backend in creating customer under the Account Information tab?

Tags: magento2, admin, customer, country-regions

I want to add country and State field at the backend in creating customer under the Account Information tab.

[image]

Based on the Country selected the State should filter in the dropdown.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in admin form block in _prepareForm() add country and region

that is

in __construct() add country config source

```
protected $_countryFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country $countryFactory,
        \[Vendor]\[ModuleName]\Model\Status $status,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        $this->_status = $status;
        $this->_countryFactory = $countryFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }
```

and  in _prepareForm()

```
     protected function _prepareForm()
        {
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    old field 
    .
    .
    .
    .
    $optionsc=$this->_countryFactory->toOptionArray();
            $country = $fieldset->addField(
                'country_id',
                'select',
                [
                    'name' => 'country_id',
                    'label' => __('Country'),
                    'title' => __('Country'),
               // 'onchange' => 'getstate(this)',
                    'values' => $optionsc,
                ]
            );
            //$optionsc=$this->_countryFactory->toOptionArray();
            $fieldset->addField(
                'region_id',
                'select',
                [
                    'name' => 'region_id',
                    'label' => __('Region'),
                    'title' => __('Region'),
                    'values' =>  ['--Please Select Country--'],
                ]
            );


         /*
            * Add Ajax to the Country select box html output
            */
      $country->setAfterElementHtml("   
            <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    require([
                    'jquery',
                    'mage/template',
                    'jquery/ui',
                    'mage/translate'
                ],
                function($, mageTemplate) {
                   $('#edit_form').on('change', '#country_id', function(event){
                        $.ajax({
                               url : '". $this->getUrl('test/*/regionlist') . "country/' +  $('#country_id').val(),
                                type: 'get',
                                dataType: 'json',
                               showLoader:true,
                               success: function(data){
                                    $('#region_id').empty();
                                    $('#region_id').append(data.htmlconent);
                               }
                            });
                   })
                }

            );
            </script>"
        );
$form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
```

and create admin side action file to get region 
that is 
app\code[Vendor][ModuleName]\Controller\Adminhtml\Lists\Regionlist.php

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

namespace [Vendor]\[ModuleName]\Controller\Adminhtml\Lists;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Regionlist extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
            /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
         */
        protected $resultPageFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory
     */
    protected $_countryFactory;

        /**
         * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
         * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory resultPageFactory
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
        )
        {
            $this->_countryFactory = $countryFactory;
            $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }
    /**
     * Default customer account page
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {


        $countrycode = $this->getRequest()->getParam('country');
        $state = "<option value=''>--Please Select--</option>";
        if ($countrycode != '') {
            $statearray =$this->_countryFactory->create()->setId(
                    $countrycode
                )->getLoadedRegionCollection()->toOptionArray();
            foreach ($statearray as $_state) {
                if($_state['value']){
                    $state .= "<option >" . $_state['label'] . "</option>";
            }
           }
        }
       $result['htmlconent']=$state;
         $this->getResponse()->representJson(
            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data')->jsonEncode($result)
        );
    } 

  }
```

once you change country region will load same way you can do for city also

If any one know better then this solution as like in we use in edit.phtml please share us

Comment: Okay will try your answer.